# 'Ask Question' button has a nav element inside in the new layout

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions, new-nav

Picture's worth a thousand words?
[image: panoramic-view]

Closer:

[image: close-up]

This only happens if I go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions, on https://stackoverflow.com/ it's fine.

The html that is inside:

```
<nav class="question-list-layout ">
     <ul>
         <li>
            <a class="collapsed selected" data-tab-options="{&quot;isExpanded&quot;:false}" href="/questions/tagged/asp.net-core">collapsed</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="expanded " data-tab-options="{&quot;isExpanded&quot;:true}" href="/questions/tagged/asp.net-core?layout=expanded">expanded</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

Seems it's position is a bit off :)

This is on chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit).
Happens everytime, can readily reproduce it.

**UPDATE**

Funny, if I go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions there's the button with the boxes inside.

But if I go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ (notice the slash at the end there) there's no button, just the layout buttons.

Comment: I saw that the first time the new nav came out.  But the Ask Question button has been moved from where you show it in your question https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OBEF.png You might want to do a hard refresh.

Comment: Nope, I logged out and back in again. Tried clearing application cache and  disabled caching in F12 tools. No joy. Your screenshot seems so to be of the old nav?

Comment: Hmm, I'm seeing the old nav again.  But my screenshot was from the new nav (the old nav doesn't have those two overlay buttons).  They're still tinkering, so I guess some unexpected css failures are to be expected for a bit.

Comment: @Will there are currently two different "new navs". This question is talking about the new top nav combined with the old new nav, where you are talking about the the old top nav with the old new nav. This user is seeing the old new nav with the new top nav. The new top nav moves the ask question button to where those two buttons are that were introduced by the old new nav. I'm going to hazard a guess and say that those little buttons are absolutely positioned, which is causing the interference.

Comment: We should really come up with some less ambiguous terms for these things

Comment: Nah.  I mean nav.

Comment: @Will disambiguation fail.